# react-native could not find store in the context of connect(component)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, redux

hope one can give me a hint, so here's my Redux implementation in react-native app:

**my app.js:**
just set up my store in this file and wrap my container in Provider just like my mentor did.

```
import React from 'react';
import Welcome from './screens/Welcome';
import ShowCase from './screens/ShowCase';
import ProductDetails from './screens/ProductDetails';

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './Reducer';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const pushRouteOne = createStackNavigator({
  page1: {
    screen: Welcome
  },
  page2: {
    screen: ShowCase
  },
  page3: {
    screen: ProductDetails
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'page1',
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none'
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(pushRouteOne);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppContainer />
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default AppContainer;
```

**this is my action file:** I use `Axios` to fetch some data from a fake API.

```
import {GET_BOOK} from './../Types/type';
import axios from 'axios';

const getBook = async (books) => {
  const res = await axios.get('https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Books');
  dispatch(getAsync(res.data));
  return {
    type: GET_BOOK,
    payload: res
  }
};

export default getBook;
```

**here is my reducer:** I should mention that I combine reducers but I don't think it's useful to put the code here, but if you need to check that out I will update the question.

```
import {GET_BOOK} from '../Types/type';

const bookReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_BOOK:
      state = action.payload;
      return {
        data: state,
        alert: false
      };

      default:
        return state;
  }
}

export default bookReducer;
```

and this is my welcome page which is the first page :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import getbook from './../Action/get_book';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreator} from 'redux';


const Welcome = (props) => {

  const navigationOptions = ({
    navigation
  }) => {
    const {
      params = {}
    } = navigation.state;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.img_container}>
        <Image style={styles.shop_img} source={require('../Images/shopping.png')} />
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn_main} onPress={() => {
        const { navigate } = props.navigation;
        navigate('page2');
      }}>
        <Text style={styles.welc_text}>Get Started</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    books : state.book
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
bindActionCreator({
  Getbook : getbook
}, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Welcome)
```

and the error I encounter is `"could not find store in the context of Connect(Welcome)"`. I saw some answers that suggest use `Provider` in the `index.js` file, I try that too but I got same result. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `export default AppContainer;`

do `export default App;`

Answer (score 0):

You have alot of problems with your code will try to summarize all

- App.js --> I think you are using redux thunk for side effects(api calls) but you are not connecting thunk to your store.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

more in docs https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

- I assume you action is correct but there is missing some code of your part
- Your reducer is correct
- Your welcome component is functional component so instead of map actions and props use hooks

```
const Welcome = (props) => {

  const navigationOptions = ({
    navigation
  }) => {
    const {
      params = {}
    } = navigation.state;
  }
  //Dispatch actions
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const bookActions = bindActionCreators({
    Getbook : getbook
  }, dispatch);
  // selector
  const books = useSelector(state => state.books);
   
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.img_container}>
        <Image style={styles.shop_img} source={require('../Images/shopping.png')} />
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn_main} onPress={() => {
        const { navigate } = props.navigation;
        navigate('page2');
      }}>
        <Text style={styles.welc_text}>Get Started</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Welcome;
```